# (node:7016) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated

Tags: node.js, ajax

I want to upload the file from ajax to node.js.code is working perfectly.but it shows deprecated.like

**(node:7016) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated**.

what is the problem in nodejs code.can anyone solve the issue?Thankyou

```html
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/index.html'));
});

app.post('/upload', function(req, res){

  console.log("get");
 
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  form.multiples = true;

  form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads');

 
  form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));
  });


  form.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err);
  });

 
  form.on('end', function() {
    res.end('success');
  });

 
  form.parse(req);

});

var server = app.listen(8086, function(){
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.rename()` is asynchronous and takes a callback which is called when the rename is done. Node is warning you because you are ignoring this, which is usually a mistake.

You should probably at least check for errors, which should make the warning go away:

```
form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name), function(err){
        console.log("Error renaming file:", err );
     }
});
```

More here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Answer (score 0):

fs asynchronous functions now demand a callback. You can fix your code by updating this line:

fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));

by this one:
fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name),(error) => { /* handle error */ }))

You can check below documentation as well.
see https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback